# Java functions by passing parameters

Tags: java

```
static int bump(int i) { 
    return i+2; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 5 ; bump(x))  
        System.out.print(x+" ");
    }
}
```

I get infinite loop of 0

Need output: 0 2 4 6

Comment: replace `bump(x)` with `x=bump(x)`

Comment: use `for (int x = 0; x < 5; x = bump(x)) {` ,you need store `bump(x)` return value for the `x`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting infinite loop because you called `bump()` without storing it

To fix this problem you need to replace `x` value with the returned value of `bump()`.

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < 5 ; x = bump(x))  
    System.out.print(x+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `0 2 4 6` as the output, this should do it.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 6; x=bump(x))
            System.out.print(x + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The last section of the `for()` loop is the *step* section. That's where you should update your loop variable. In your case, you should update the `x` variable like this:

```
static int bump(int i) { 
    return i+2; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x = bump(x))  
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}
```

I am not sure where you got this idea of using a function to update the loop variable, but this is not very common. You may consider just getting rid of the `bump()` function and make the step section readable and clear, like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x += 2)  
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```